# Как откатить проект до версии на GitHub?

Tags: git, github

Как откатить проект до версии на GitHub? На GitHub лежит проект, я у себя на компе сделал изменения и даже не коммитил, после понял что лучше этих изменений не делать и хочу вернуть все как было на момент последнего коммита.
`git fetch`, `git pull` пробовал, `git clone` тоже пробовал, все не то.

Comment: git revert --continue пробовали? Но вообще странно, что git clone вам не помог, ведь там создаётся новая папка с исходниками, которые лежат удалённо.

Comment: чтобы git revert воспользоваться, я так полагаю надо сперва коммит сделать, а потом откатить его?

Comment: git clone копирует только те файлы, что есть на git Hub, а у меня на компе еще часть в игноре, в итоге после git clone часть файлов не досчитался

Comment: Блин, да, в общем я запутался и оказался неправ, в Intellij IDEA есть revert, который позволяет откатить файлы на состояние коммита, поэтому и полез искать по гиту его. Ответ с reset --hard верный. По поводу clone, я думал вы в другую папку пытались склонировать.

Comment: Советую использовать GitExtension. Он удобнее классического Git GUI.

Comment: оставил ещё один вариант - с карманом.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Используйте reset:

```
git reset --hard @{u}
```

Comment: Коммита не было, ветка никуда не уехала, reset некуда сделать

Comment: Такой вариант тоже рабоатет

Comment: Автор не говорил, что создавал новую ветку. Судя по этому, он находится в мастере, и reset будет сделан до головного коммита мастера.

Comment: А, ну хотя да, согласен

Comment: "Автор не говорил, что создавал новую ветку", но он и не говорил,  что ее не создал. Обычно новые изменения делают не в master.

Comment: Презумпция недосказанности говорит, что не было, пока не сказано обратное)

Answer (score 1):

Я в подобных случаях делаю `git reset --hard HEAD` - это практически то же самое, что и ответ @АлександрГрушко.

Существующие файлы, о которых гит не знает, вы не удалите таким способом<s>, но тут уже никак, разве что вы сами удалите эти файлы</s>. (@D-side подсказывает, что можно воспользоваться командой `git clean -df` – удаляет все файлы в папке, которые не относятся к проекту и не сохранены в репозитории)

Альтернативно, можете забрать изменения в карман и тут же его опустошить:

```
git stash
git stash drop
```

Comment: "тут уже никак, разве что вы сами удалите эти файлы" -- чем, кстати, занимается `git clean` (с определёнными флагами).

Comment: @D-side Кстати, выходит, если часть файлов в .gitignore и соответственно в контроле версий не участвует, то командой `git clean -df` их не подотрешь случайно, верно? Я  так понял параметр `-df` должен не позволить ему перестараться или я не правильно понял?

Comment: @AleksandrSergeevich "не перестараться" ему говорит **отсутствие** среди опций `x` (которая как раз говорит "и не смотри на гитигноры"). И вообще, [есть же инструкция](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) :)

Comment: "это практически то же самое" - [не совсем так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474577/what-does-the-argument-u-mean-in-git). Поэтому, по моему мнению, этот ответ более правильный и полный. Вместо HEAD лучше @, на 3-и знака короче.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать `git checkout [имя файла]`, подробнее [тут](http://marklodato.github.io/visual-git-guide/index-ru.html#checkout)

Comment: checkout не вернёт файлы в состояние с сервера

Comment: Да, не вернет, но зачем его брать с сервера, если оно есть в папке .git

Comment: Ой, да, но всё равно, если коммита не было, то он изменённые в данный момент файлы не вернёт в предыдущее состояние коммита, нужен revert

Comment: @Komdosh а разве не reset?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, reset же ветку возвращает на коммит, а ему насколько я понимаю, надо тупо откатить текущие изменения

Comment: Только что попробовал - получилось с checkout.

Comment: @DiDex, что вы попробовали? Изменили файлы без коммита, а потом checkout на ту же ветку? Он же пишет `Already on 'branchName'`

Comment: Нет, съел и откатил файл.

Comment: @DiDex я попробовал с checkout, он не удалил лишнюю информацию

Comment: если поменялось много файлов - то надоест для каждого делать чекаут, так что вариант так себе.

Comment: Можно сделать git checkout .

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте git reset --mixed с указанием ветки, должно отмениться ваше добавление без коммита

Comment: git reset --mixed вроде же не трогает рабочую копию в принципе? Кажется, это совершенно не то что нужно автору...

Comment: вроде как автор и не коммитил, я так полагаю речь идет про локальный репозиторий, который он просто хочет отменить добавления и не хочет наткнутся на конфликты. В данном случае можно при не желании танцевать с бубном удалить весь репозиторий с локалки и склонировать заново :)

Answer (score 0):

**Решение:**

Вижу в вопросе, что вы не делали комит, если также вы не добавляли измененные файлы в индекс командой `git add`, то можете воспользоваться командой:

```
git checkout -- .
```

Эта команда делает откат изменных файлов к их исходному состоянию, т.е. состоянию когда не было совершенно каких либо изменения.

**Теория:**

Откуда Git узнает, на какой ветке вы находитесь в данный момент? Он хранит специальный указатель, который называется HEAD (верхушка).

- **git reset** - обновляет индекс, перемещая его на HEAD.
- **git checkout** - обновляет рабочую ветку. HEAD будет обновлен в случае, если вы делаете переход с ветки на ветку.

**О главном:**

Необходимо понимать что вы хотите получить после ввода команды. Более детально описано здесь - [ссылка на статью](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD-reset).